# Masking ID and Name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a use case where there is a free text field and the user id in the format ab12345 (fixed) and name (dynamic) can appear anywhere in the string.

Now I need to replace the ab12345 with xxxxxxx and the names also with XXXX wherever I find them in the string.

I used:

```sql
select *
from dbo.TEST
WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

to get the user id ab12345 but I am unable to write the replace function for this since the result is dynamic.

Same with the name as well.

Comment: How are you going to know where in the string the name us; what else is in the string. Some sample data would help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So the string would be something like "An infraction was raised on user id ab12345, and the name of the complainant is John." and the expected result is "An infraction was raised on user id XXXXXXX, and the name of the complainant is XXXX."

Comment: what defines the universe of names?

Comment: @SteveC we have a HR Database from which we can get employee names, but for now if you look at the example above and the expected results where the id and names are masked out, I can replicate with my data.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Add all information relating to your question in the question. Do you have a list of userIds and names stored?

Comment: @Stu these are employee names that cannot be shared. If you can just take the example I gave you above and tell me how to replace the dummy name John and id ab12345 I can apply in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the following may help in redacting the userID

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE TABLE #CustComments
( CustomerID INT
, CustomerNotes VARCHAR(8000)
)
GO
INSERT dbo.#CustComments
        ( CustomerID
        , CustomerNotes
        )
    VALUES
       ( 1, 'An infraction was raised on user id ab12345, and the name of the complainant is John')
     , ( 2, 'The customer was not happy with person CD45678 and is going to ask William Jones to speak with George Hillman about this matter' )
     , ( 3, 'A customer called and repeatedly mentioned the name of employee ZX98765 and assumes their name was Janet which is not correct')

SELECT * , 
 PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes) start_pos,
 SUBSTRING (customernotes, (PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes)) ,7 ) extractstring,
 REPLACE(customernotes, substring (customernotes, (PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes)) ,7 ), 'XXXXXXX') redacted

FROM #CustComments

--TIDY UP
DROP TABLE #CustComments
```

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

if you have or can create a table of "names"...this may work

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE TABLE #CustComments (
  CustomerID int,
  CustomerNotes varchar(8000)
)
GO
INSERT #CustComments (CustomerID
, CustomerNotes)
  VALUES (1, 'An infraction was raised on user id ab12345 , and the name of the complainant is Ann')
  , (2, 'The customer was not happy with person CD45678 and is going to ask Richard Jones to speak with Todd Hillman about this matter')
  , (3, 'A customer called and repeatedly mentioned the name of employee ZX98765 and assumes their name was Shana which is not correct')

CREATE TABLE #empname (
  ename varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO #empname ([ename])
  VALUES ('Zeph'), ('Ebony'), ('Felicia'), ('Benedict'), ('Ahmed'), ('Ira'), ('Julie'), ('Levi'),
  ('Sebastian'), ('Fiona'), ('Lamar'), ('Russell'), ('Abdul'), ('Lev'), ('Isaiah'), ('Charlotte'),
  ('Rowan'), ('Ivory'), ('Quinn'), ('Jordan'), ('Xantha'), ('Shana'), ('Mufutau'), ('Jessamine'),
  ('Desirae'), ('Yvette'), ('Odessa'), ('Ray'), ('Ori'), ('Zenaida'), ('Allegra'), ('Allistair'),
  ('Raymond'), ('Martena'), ('Cameron'), ('Ila'), ('Nigel'), ('Dale'), ('Emerald'), ('Guinevere'),
  ('Boris'), ('Dolan'), ('Ainsley'), ('Madeson'), ('Kadeem'), ('Ciaran'), ('Hop'), ('Louis'),
  ('Maia'), ('Hiroko'), ('Hakeem'), ('Cole'), ('Tyrone'), ('Amy'), ('Doris'), ('Keaton'),
  ('Carlos'), ('Richard'), ('Lysandra'), ('Beverly'), ('Hamish'), ('Demetria'), ('Eric'), ('Nayda'),
  ('Sydney'), ('Fritz'), ('Blaze'), ('Regina'), ('Ciara'), ('Ina'), ('Joan'), ('Risa'),
  ('Alea'), ('Denton'), ('Daryl'), ('Mollie'), ('Keane'), ('Jarrod'), ('Ann'), ('Juliet'), 
  ('Germaine'), ('Alexa'), ('Zane'), ('Kiona'), ('Armand'), ('Jin'), ('Geraldine'), ('Natalie'),
  ('Nomlanga'), ('Todd'), ('Rajah'),('Lucian'), ('Idona'), ('Autumn'), ('Briar'),
  -- add surname
  ('Hillman');
  ;
  
-- redact the userID std format
SELECT 
CustomerID , 
 --PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes) start_pos,
 --SUBSTRING (customernotes, (PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes)) ,7 ) extractstring,
 REPLACE(customernotes, substring (customernotes, (PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', CustomerNotes)) ,7 ), 'XXXXXXX') ID_redacted
 INTO #ID_REDACT
FROM #CustComments

-- split into rows
SELECT customerId,  value  
into #SPLIT
FROM #ID_REDACT 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ID_redacted, ' ');  

--redact based on join with a ""name"" table
SELECT s.customerid,
       CASE
         WHEN e.ename IS NULL THEN s.value
         ELSE 'XXXXXXX'
       END AS name_redact
INTO #NAME_REDACT
FROM   #split AS s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #empname AS e
                    ON s.value = e.ename 

SELECT customerId, 
STRING_AGG(name_redact, ' ') as full_redact 
INTO #RESULTS
from #NAME_REDACT
group by CustomerID


-- RESULTS WITH COMPARISON
SELECT
  C.CustomerID,
  C.CustomerNotes AS Original,
  R.full_redact AS Redacted
FROM #CustComments AS C
INNER JOIN #RESULTS AS R
  ON C.CustomerID = R.customerId


--TIDY UP
DROP TABLE #CustComments
DROP TABLE #empname
DROP TABLE #ID_REDACT
DROP TABLE #SPLIT
DROP TABLE #NAME_REDACT
DROP TABLE #RESULTS
```

Comment: Thank you Graham for the code, and it worked like a charm for the ID piece. For the name bit, I do not have the STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG Functions activated on my SSMS. Is there another way I can achieve this.

Comment: Hoping you can help here GrahamH. Thanks for the code above for the userid, but I think the name is more involved.

Comment: "Hoping you can help here GrahamH. Thanks for the code above for the userid, but I think the name is more involved. – Viswanath Sitaraman 3 hours ago"     

please provide more detail and data to represent where "name is more involved"

Comment: Hi GrahamH the above example you used is fine, but the version of SQL I use has max compatibility of 120 because of which Im unable to use the STRING_SPLIT() and STRING_AGG() Functions.

Comment: ok...you will need to search for a "string splitter" ....there are many about also search for row concatenation....again several methods